# Get db results from (node - express - mongodb) to angular 4 securely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mean-stack

There is no issue b/w establishing connection b/w nodejs & angular. Also the database results are fine. This is the only problem I'm facing now.

I have 2 different ports but same server

0.0.0.0:3000 - for nodejs 
0.0.0.0:4200 - for angular

When I make an api request to node(mongodb) from angular it is visible in browser console as well as networks tab when I inpect. How can I overcome this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Angular is an SPA, a framework that works on front-end. Which means once the files of the application downloaded in the browser memory, it then launch the instance of your application.

Afterwhat, when you make a request to an API or any other URL, the browser behaves as it should : it makes the request. You have no real way to prevent this.

That doesn't mean the requests are not secure. Viewing requests made by your app in the console or the network tab doesn't mean it's not secure.

Comment: Hi Asone, Lets say if I need a user's details include user_id & triggering a request from angular, in networks tab the results are visible. Like {'_id' : 234234}  :(

Comment: I don't see where's the problem about that. 

Open any website, even fb or twitter, open the network tab and use the platforms. You'll see you can get every requests and every data exchanged beetween your browser and the servers. That's normal behavior. 

If you want to to make those data unreadable then you should consider cipher the data and implement the decipher functions into your App. This way your user won't be able to see clear data. But that won't mean it's impossible to come over. 

Again : seeing communications made with your browser is normal behavior

Comment: This is the first time I'm working with mean stack. So I'm little bit confused. For example in codeigniter framework, if we get results from db in controller (backend) it won't be visible to user until we handled any foreach like statements in frontend view files. But here it's totally different. Any how, it may be it's nature as you say :)
So we have to minimize the private datas such as passwords,other important datas as much as we can right ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use nginx as a proxy server to redirect your all REST call to overcome this.
for detailed use please visit here [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)